# Slick after refresing content with ajax it brakes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, underscore.js

I try to implement a simple carousel with slick, but the carousel items should be refreshed every few seconds via AJAX.

The problem is that slick brakes after the content is refreshed. In addition in my console I don't get any error.

So my HTML looks like that:

```
<div class="live-carousel" data-slick="off">
    <div class="score-container">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="score">
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Team A</a> <span>0</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Team B</a> <span>2</span>
                </p>
                <span class="has_info"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <dl>
                    <dt><a href="#">Team A</a></dt>
                    <dd>Player name <span>12'</span></dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By the AJAX request I create multiple `.score` items inside the `.score-container` and that's why I use the slick to make them displayed as carousel.

My javascript code is like that:

```
var getLive = function() {

var $score_flipping_cards = $( '#score_flipping_cards' );
var $live_carousel = $('.live-carousel');
var $slick = null;

if ( 0 < $score_flipping_cards.length ) {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url     : z.ajaxurl,
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : {
                action : 'get_live'
            },
            success : function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                var $template = _.template( $score_flipping_cards.html() );
                var $counter  = 0;

                if ( null !== $slick ) {
                    $live_carousel.slick('unslick');
                }

                $live_carousel.empty();

                var a = $.map(data, function(value, index) {
                                        return [value];
                });

                _.each(
                    a,
                    function( $match ) {
                        _.each(
                            $match,
                            function( $game ) {
                                var $goals = [];
                                var $template_data = {};

                                ++$counter;

                                $template_data.livePage = $game.livePageURL;
                                $template_data.team_a = $game.TeamAName;
                                $template_data.team_a_score = $game.TeamAScore;

                                $live_carousel.append( $template( $template_data ) );

                                if( $match.length === $counter ) {
                                        $slick = true;
                                        make_slick($live_carousel);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        );
    }
};

getLive();

setInterval(
    getLive,
    8000
);
```

And my slick initiation function is like that:

```
var make_slick = function ($live_carousel) {
        $live_carousel.slick (
            {
                accessibility : true,
                autoplay : true,
                cssEase : 'ease-in-out',
                easing : 'ease-in-out',
                lazyLoad : 'progressive',
                infinite       : true,
                slidesToShow   : 5,
                slidesToScroll : 5,
                dots           : true,
                speed          : 300,
                responsive     : [
                    {
                        breakpoint : 1024,
                        settings   : {
                            slidesToShow   : 5,
                            slidesToScroll : 5
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint : 600,
                        settings   : {
                            slidesToShow   : 3,
                            slidesToScroll : 3
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint : 480,
                        settings   : {
                        slidesToShow   : 1,
                        slidesToScroll : 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    );
};
```

As you can see, if the carousel has been initiated I unslick the carousel, and I initiating the slick carousel again after the items has been append in my carousel container.

the very first time the page is loading the carousel it is initiated normally, but after the second ajax call the carousel brakes.

Can someone help with that ?

Comment: reached here by searching unsolved problems, don't know the problem still exist or not. So, setInterval and the success of ajax both are running asynchronously right, so there might be a problem of synchronization of each (getLive->ajaxResponse). so you can try calling setTimeout after each ajaxResponse, and also when you call `getLive` in timer each finds the DOM objects each time, you can keep them in some variable, and use them from a inside closure function which will be running in interval.

Comment: Hello @KoushikChatterjee, and thanks for your reply. The problem solved about a year ago :). Thank you again.